# SSIS TO Merge Join two ADO.NET Source

Tags: ssis-2012

I am try to join two ADO.Net source file its cases error.Is there is any possible to merge two ADO.Net source file..While merge two OLDBE source is working file

Comment: while running the error occurs

Comment: Did you have any example pls help me

Comment: [ADO NET Source 1 1 1 1 [333]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "ADO NET Source 1 1 1 1" (333)" failed because error code 0x80004003 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "GLDCT" (366)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: This is error..If I run one by one source file it getting output....

Comment: [ADO NET Source 1 1 1 1 [333]] Error: The component "ADO NET Source 1 1 1 1" (333) was unable to process the data. Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC0209029 from a method call.

Comment: this is next to that error message

Comment: sir..pls give some example  link

Comment: sir that is the erro message ...before that Excute Phase is beginning is there

Comment: sir send ur email shall send the screan shot

Comment: [ADO NET Source 1 1 1 1 [333]] Error: The component "ADO NET Source 1 1 1 1" (333) was unable to process the data. Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC0209029 from a method call. Is this Error sir

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you.  I don't know anything about that error.   Hopefully someone else can comment.  Good luck.